# How can I have an aribtrary choice using python argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using argparse, and I'm trying to use choice to limit the options.

For the accepted values, I am looking for the input in the format of: *NUMBER*km, *NUMBER*m, *NUMBER*cm.  For example: 3493cm.  I don't care what the number is as long as it ends with a km,cm, or m.

I've tried:

```
parser.add_argument('-d','--distance',
                    choice=['*m','*km','*cm'])
```

That didn't work.

As part of my efforts to learn python, I decided to write a small unit conversion script that takes input from arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`choices` can't be used this way.  The test that `argparse` uses is

```
astr in choices
```

That matches strings in a list, tuple, keys of dictionary.  A specialized class could match with a `*` pattern, but that's more advanced.

An alternative to `choices` is to write a custom `type` function.  Or apply that function to the value after parsing.

Your first task is to come up with a function that tests whether a string meets your criteria

```
def mytest(astr):
    if astr ...:
        return astr
    else:
        raise ValueError('your message')
```

After parsing run

```
mytest(args.distance)
```

Once you get that testing working we can talk about including it in the parser.